# Does spark do local aggregation when groupBy is used?

Tags: apache-spark

I know that `rdd.groupByKey()` shuffles everything and after that proceeds with consequent operations. So if you need to group rows and transform them, `groupByKey` will shuffle all the data and only then do a transformation. Which in a case of reductive transformations and large number of rows with the same grouping key is inefficient, because number of rows inside of each partition could be reduced greatly before a shuffle with local reduction. Does `datset.groupBy()` act the same?

I'm using Spark 1.6

Comment: As soon as finished with the question I've noticed this: "_This function does not support partial aggregation, and as a result requires shuffling all the data in the Dataset. If an application intends to perform an aggregation over each key, it is best to use the reduce function or an org.apache.spark.sql.expressions#Aggregator._" in mapGroups method i wanted to use https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedDataset

Comment: Seems like combineByKey is what I need, it does aggregation locally.